# db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified or db.Set<X>().AddOrUpdate(x)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api

I would like to know the which one is the best way for updating an entity between:

method 1. `db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;` AND

method 2. `db.Set<X>().AddOrUpdate(x);`

I've always used method 1, until it broke last week because for some reason, EF lost track of the entity i was trying to update. And someone mentioned that manually re-attaching the entity will make the system vulnerable.

Anyway, which is better and what are the pros and cons of each. Thank you.

Comment: "someone mentioned that manually re-attaching the entity will make the system vulnerable" - was this argued somehow? `AddOrUpdate` attaches entity as well, if it was found in store.

Answer (score 0):

1). **db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;**

**Pros**

a). 1 x query on database to update

**Cons**

a). Can’t specify which properties change

b). Views must contain every property

2). **db.Set().AddOrUpdate(x);**

The extension method AddOrUpdate(this DbSet) allows you to do exactly what I want to do: Insert if it's not there and update if it found an existing value. 
This method will be faster than the former.

You can also refer https://andrearegoli.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/entity-framework-update-without-select-part-1/

hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Archana ParmarArc. And the link is really helpful. I didn't know there were more options for updateing

Comment: I am glad I could help :-)